# Rescue data from corupted FAT32 micro SD card

Tags: fat32, micro-sd

I used it on android and it just stopped working. I want to extract data before I format it. Here's the output of `sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/mmcblk0p1`:

```
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
Boot sector contents:
System ID "android "
Media byte 0xf0 (5.25" or 3.5" HD floppy)
       512 bytes per logical sector
     32768 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 16384 (sector 32)
         2 FATs, 32 bit entries
   2022912 bytes per FAT (= 3951 sectors)
Root directory start at cluster 2 (arbitrary size)
Data area starts at byte 4062208 (sector 7934)
    505668 data clusters (16569729024 bytes)
16 sectors/track, 4 heads
         0 hidden sectors
  32370688 sectors total
Checking file /
/
  Contains a free cluster (2). Assuming EOF.
FAT32 root dir starts with a bad cluster!
```

Is it possible to save data? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ddrescue` to make a copy of the SD card - you don't want to work off of the original.

You can use `TestDisk` or `Autopsy` to try recovering the filesystem or a tool like `scalpel` to carve files from the disk.

Here are some basic commands:

### ddrescue

`ddrescue` is used in a similar fashion to `dd`. Namely:

```
ddrescue /dev/XXX /home/user/Desktop/copy_of_sd_card /home/user/Desktop/logfile
```

The `logfile` will store the information about any sectors it had trouble reading.

[Source](http://ss64.com/bash/ddrescue.html).

### [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

You can then use `TestDisk` to try to retrieve files from the image:

```
testdisk /home/user/Desktop/copy_of_sd_card
```

It has a wizard-like interface. as well. A full guide is [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

### Autopsy

`Autospy` is a graphical interface over the sleuth kit. When you run it, it creates a web interface.

[This site](http://cyfor.isis.poly.edu/16-view_modules.html?view=15-tsk__autopsy) has a simple walkthrough on how to use Autopsy.

Also, see [this](http://www.sleuthkit.org/autopsy/v2/)

Comment: I'm not used to that programs. Can you give me specific commands? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I just added some.

Answer (score 4):

### [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

As long as files on your SD card haven't been physically overwritten there is always possible to recover them, even if SD card is reformatted. I recommend using the PhotoRec program, it is easy to use command line tool.

Comment: This saved my day since I already tried testdisk but did not find the option within.